# How to do loop with parameter steps

Tags: procedural-programming

How to do loop with parameter steps

For example

I want print numbers : 1,2,4,8,16

but I don't know how to do loop

code like this doesn't work

Do[ Print[i] , {i, 1, 10, i}]

Comment: Or, using *Mathematica* idioms (which are recommended), do `Table[2^n, {n,0,9}]` or `2^Range[0, 10]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Do` does not support variable step. You can use `For` etc. instead.

```
Block[{i}, For[i = 1, i < 10, i += i^2, Print[i]]]

NestWhileList[# + #^2 &, 1, # <= 10 &]
```

By the way, your example is just `Do[ Print[2^i] , {i, 0, 9}]`.

Comment: I'm interested in parameter steps not this example

Answer (score 0):

Define iteration step as a function of current value of iterator (simple in this particular case):

```
step[i_] := i
```

Next we can generate values of iterator with this varying step:

```
values = NestList[# + step[#], 1, 10]
```

> `{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}`

And use this values in iteration:

```
Do[Print[i], {i, values}]
```